# Tabularx remove extra padding before row

Tags: tabularx

I've got a `tabularx` containing figures that is set to `\textwidth` but doesn't occupy whole `textwdith` and leaves a margin on the left. Specifically:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{A B C}

% num_web_clicks
\rowcolor{red}\multicolumn{3}{B}{\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\input{fig1.pgf}}
\\
\rowcolor{blue}\resizebox{.33\textwidth}{!}{\input{fig2.pgf}}
&\resizebox{.33\textwidth}{!}{\input{fig3.pgf}} 
&\resizebox{.33\textwidth}{!}{\input{fig4.pgf}}\\

\end{tabularx}
```

Where column types are defined as:

```
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{B}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{A}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
```

Which looks like this:

[image: what the problem looks like]

Why does each row have a margin on the left (red/blue extra space before the row, on the left) and how can I remove it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why does each row have a margin on the left (red/blue extra space before the row, on the left) and how can I remove it?

Just change

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{A B C}
```

either to

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}A@{}B@{}C@{}}
```

or to

```
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{A B C}
```